# Lifting - generalization

Tags: haskell, lifting

I need to use heavy function lifting, eg.

```
k = myFunc
  <$> someFunctionName 1
  <*> someFunctionName 2
  <*> someFunctionName 3
  <*> someFunctionName 4
  <*> someFunctionName 5
  <*> someFunctionName 6
  <*> someFunctionName 8
  <*> someFunctionName 9
  -- ...
```

Which is not provided for bigger functions (about 20 arguments) by Prelude. Is there smart way to do such a lift without explicitly chaining those `ap`s? I am looking for something like

```
k = magic (map someFunctionName [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9]) myFunc
```

I may be hard to guess the type of `magic` as it depends on number of arguments of lifted function. It is of course not possible to use `map` on list here (or is it?), I put it only as a viewpoint.

I think I am looking for something that could be nicely solved by dependent types, which are not included in Haskell, but maybe there is some tricky way to workaround it (TemplateHaskell?)

Do you have any ideas how to make it more elegant and flexible?

**edit:** In my case types of chained functions are all the same.

Comment: If you wonder what am I doing, I am converting csv records into haskell record of about 23 fields, and instance declaration of `FromRecord` looks like in the question, where `myFunc` is constructor and `someFunctionName` is `unsafeIndex`

Comment: Are all of the arguments of the same type?

Comment: I seriously doubt it's a good idea to represent such a big CSV by a monolithic Haskell record. Why do you do this?

Comment: In this case types of functions are the same. I shall edit question. 
This data is impossible to split in reasonable way

Comment: You could define `liftM23`, but I doubt this will be "nicer" than a long chain of `<*>`s. In fact, I'd probably find that the nicest for a lot less arguments than 23; they chain nicely across lines whereas e.g. `liftM2` is neat because the arguments fit totally on one line. Have you considered designing your Haskell records in such a way that they only contain partitions of the CSV-file that are relevant to certain applications? Generally, if your functions have 23 arguments, they're doing too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Lift constructors

Using type classes we can define a generalized version of `liftA`/`ap`. The tricky part is to infer when to stop lifting and return the result. Here we use the fact that constructors are curried functions with as many arguments as they have fields, and the result type is not a function.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Text.Read

-- apF
--   :: Applicative f
--   => (i -> f a)
--   -> (a -> a -> ... ->   x)   -- constructor type
--   -> (i -> i -> ... -> f x)   -- lifted function
class Applicative f => ApF f i a s t where
  apF :: (i -> f a) -> f s -> t

-- Recursive case
-- s ~ (a -> ...)
-- t ~ (i -> ...)
instance (a ~ a', t ~ (i -> t'), ApF f i a s' t') => ApF f i a (a' -> s') t where
  apF parseArg fconstr i = apF parseArg (fconstr <*> parseArg i)

-- Base case
-- s ~   x  -- x assumed not to be a function type (not (y -> z) for any y and z)
-- t ~ f x
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (t ~ f x, Applicative f) => ApF f i a x t where
  apF _ fconstr = fconstr

liftF :: ApF f i a s t => (i -> f a) -> s -> t
liftF parseArg constr = apF parseArg (pure constr)

main = do
  let lookup :: Int -> Maybe Integer
      lookup i =
        case drop i [2,3,5,7,11,13] of
          [] -> Nothing
          a : _ -> Just a
  print $ liftF lookup (,,) 0 2 5
```

## Higher-kinded records and generics

- [Blog post on representing records as higher-kinded data](http://reasonablypolymorphic.com//blog/higher-kinded-data)
- [generics-sop documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop)
- [Gist of this answer](https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/8fc397cf55c436e69d2390df1301cea7)

Another solution is to first parameterize records by a type function wrapping every field, so that we can put things of various other related types. Those allow us to produce and consume actual records by traversing those derived structures using Haskell Generics.

```
data UserF f = User
  { name :: f @@ String
  , age :: f @@ Int
  } deriving G.Generic

type User = UserF Id
```

Type functions are defined using the type family `(@@)` (`HKD` in the blog post linked above). The ones relevant to this answer are the identity and constant functions.

```
type family s @@ x
type instance Id   @@ x = x
type instance Cn a @@ x = a

data Id
data Cn (a :: *)
```

For example, we can gather the indices used to parse CSV, in a `UserF (Cn Int)`:

```
userIxes = User { name = 0, age = 2 } :: UserF (Cn Int)
```

Given such a parameterized record type (`p = UserF`), and a record of indices (`ixes :: p (Cn Int)`), we can parse a CSV record (`r :: [String]`) with `parseRec` below. Here using [*generics-sop*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop-0.3.2.0/docs/Generics-SOP.html).

```
parseRec :: _
         => p (Cn Int) -> [String] -> Maybe (p Id)
parseRec ixes r =
  fmap to .
  hsequence .
  htrans (Proxy :: Proxy ParseFrom) (\(I i) -> read (r !! i)) .
  from $
  ixes
```

Let us break down the code bottom-up. *generics-sop* provides combinators to transform records in a uniform way that is like using lists. It is best to follow a proper tutorial to understand the underlying details, but for the sake of demonstration, we will imagine that the middle of the pipeline between `from` and `to` is actually transforming lists, using a dynamic type `Field` to type heterogeneous lists.

- `from` turns a record into its heterogeneous list of fields, but since they're all `Int` the list is really homogeneous for now `from :: p (Cn Int) -> [Int]`.
- Here using `(!!)` and `read`, we get and parse each field using the given index `i`. `htrans Proxy` is basically `map`: `(Int -> Maybe Field) -> [Int] -> [Maybe Field]`.
- `hsequence` is basically `sequence :: [Maybe Field] -> Maybe [Field]`.
- `to` turns a list of fields into a record with compatible field types, `[Field] -> p Id`.

The final step is effortless:

```
parseUser :: Record -> Maybe User
parseUser = parseRec $ User { name = 0, age = 2 }
```